# Value of array does not change

Tags: java

```
public static void update(int i , int[] dp){
           dp[0]=i;

}

public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException {

int[][] dp = new int[10][100001];

update(100,dp[0]);
System.out.println(dp[0][0]) // Showing 0 instead of 100



}
```

Why the value of `dp` does not change  as they were changing in c++ , i have tried using declare it global by using `static int[][] dp` before main ,
Why it is not changing it's value.

Comment: It prints 100. Are you using a different program and presenting us with a simplified version? (That would explain the `throws IOException`)? If so, you need to post the version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

This is changing!!!
I tested this by NetBeans IDE7.4 and shows result ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yes, but my reputation is 40 and can't commented.

Comment: @Masoud Hosseini It's 50 now. Comment as much as you like :)

Comment: @pbabcdefp like, tanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method

```
update(100,dp[0]);
```

So the value of `i` is 100, and the method thus changes the value of the 100th element of the array. And then you check the value of `dp[0][0]`.

Comment: With your update, and if you add the missing semicolon at the end of the println statement, it compiles and runs as expected: it prints 100: http://ideone.com/VnPTt3

Answer (score 0):

Try printing

```
System.out.println(dp[0][100]);
```

You passed on dp[0] to you method and passed index as 100, and hence you ended up setting dp[0][100] as i i.e. 100.

Try calling update method as:

```
update(0,dp[0]);
```

But this wont have effect as in update method you are setting value similar to parameter i that we are passing as 0.

Answer (score 0):

The value is updated to 100 perfectly. I checked in eclipse. check it correctly.